# django admin more than one ForeignKey for admin.TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to implement a form with a subform in the admin section.

```
form = Fighter()
subform = FighterFightHistory() //All of his fights
```

**My issue is the following:**

```
<class 'fighters.admin.Fights'>: (admin.E202) 'fighters.FighterFightHistory' has more than one ForeignKey to 'fighters.Fighter'.
```

So how do I make the form show a drop down for each foreign key (`fighter`, `opponent`).

The 2 foreign key are (see below):

- A link to the fighter (`fighter`)
- A link to the opponent (`opponent`)

**fighters/models.py**

```
class FighterFightHistory(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey('events.Event', null=True)
    fight = models.ForeignKey('fights.Fight', null=True)
    fighter = models.ForeignKey(Fighter, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_fighter', null=True)
    howitended = models.ForeignKey('fights.HowItEnded', null=True)
    opponent = models.ForeignKey(Fighter, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_opponent', null=True)

    ended_in_round = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    youtube_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    win = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**fighters/admin.py**

```
class Fights(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FighterFightHistory
    extra = 30


class FighterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name', 'history_completed', 'modified', 'active')
    search_fields = ['name']
    inlines = [Fights, ]
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This solved my problem (using **fk_name**):

```
class Fights(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FighterFightHistory
    extra = 30
    fk_name = 'fighter'
```

Comment: this fixed the same issue for me too, although, i'd be curious why this fixes the issue. by adding a `fk_name` does django now treat `fighter` as the main FK and `opponent` is somehow treated differently?

similar to the original post, i needed to have two FKs to model, but i did not want to use a m2m field.

Comment: Using `fk_name` was key for me also for a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was, that you could use ManyToMany-Fields and then limit the number of relations to two. But then I thought, that you never can be sure which Fighter-Object represents which type.

Then I had a short look into the Django-Docs and found something that should answer your problem: [Django-Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/?utm_content=buffer3f192&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields)

The interesting part is:

> Membership has two foreign keys to Person (person and inviter), which makes the relationship ambiguous and Django can’t know which one to use. In this case, you must explicitly specify which foreign keys Django should use using through_fields, as in the example above.

I hope that this helps you.